# Why indefinite article with "imagination"?

Tags: nouns, articles, uncountable-nouns

*Imagination* can't be counted. But I have seen some people using the indefinite article in front of *imagination*.

For example, "Everyone has an imagination."

What makes that correct, grammatically?

Comment: Can you cite a reference or dictionary definition that says "imagination can't be counted"?

Comment: Have you checked a good dictionary?

Comment: Coffee can't be counted. But I'm about to have a coffee. Or two. // Certain dictionaries are better than others in this area. Check [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/imagination) for at least one clear example of the count usage. But also be aware that even non-count nouns occasionally accept the indefinite article (The representative spoke at the meeting yesterday with an enormous enthusiasm.  / The representative spoke at the meeting yesterday with enormous enthusiasm. / *The representative spoke at the meetings last week with enormous enthusiasms.)

Answer (score 0):

**Imagination** - the ability of the mind to be creative or resourceful.

Because someone has **an** ability of the mind to be creative or resourceful, one therefore also has **an** imagination.

Comment: An answer needs to have authoritative references to be of real value. Also, the count / non-count issue has been addressed at length here before.

Comment: Using the example of "an ability" to argue for the correctness of "an imagination" is plainly unsupportable. If I have many mental abilities, it doesn't follow that I have many imaginations.